# Spring Expression Language (SPEL) limit access to bean fields with a given annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I need to evaluate a dynamic user-generated expression based on a bean using the Spring Expression Language, but I wish to limit the fields they can use via an annotation. For example, if I had the below class I would like to be able to evaluate the expression `field1 + field2`, but if I tried to evaluate `field1 + field3` this would lead to an exception being generated.

Is this possible? Is there a different way to limit the scope of the expression?

```
public class Foo {

    @AllowedField
    private int field1;

    @AllowedField
    private int field2;

    private int field3;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Take a look: https://dzone.com/articles/simple-attribute-based-access-control-with-spring

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not possible out-of-the-box - but you can probably right something like a Resolver yourself, then enforce that constraint..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, this is what you need to do

Extend `StandardEvaluationContext` to return your own `PropertyAccessor`:

```
public class SecureEvaluationContext extends StandardEvaluationContext {
    @Override
    public List<PropertyAccessor> getPropertyAccessors() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SecurePropertyAccessor());
    }
}
```

Extend `ReflectivePropertyAccessor` and implemet your own `canRead`:

```
public class SecurePropertyAccessor extends ReflectivePropertyAccessor {

    @Override
    public  boolean canRead(EvaluationContext context, Object target, String name) {
        boolean canRead = // Add your own logic as needed
        return canRead;
    }
}
```

Evaluate with:

```
    Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("field1 + field2");
    EvaluationContext evaluationContext = new SecureEvaluationContext();
    Double value = expression.getValue(evaluationContext, new ControlElement(), Double.class);
```